# Excel cover sheet that is used to populate cells across the whole workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a cover sheet for an excel workbook, the user will populate these cells then a macro will paste them across all worksheets inside the workbook.

The cover sheet asks for information in cells from column D and column I which could be common across the whole workbook. I am trying to make filling out this workbook faster and easier.

I have a basic understanding of Excel VBA but require help to write this, thank you.

Comment: This is very broad. If you have a basic understanding of Excel VBA, you surely have already written some code for this task? It sounds as if you just need to loop over the sheets and fill some cells. A userform to enter the data could also be a solution (depending on the data that is entered).

Comment: I'm sorry for being broad. The only code I have I have gained from this site, like `Set targetRange = newSheet.[A1]` `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:Q1").Copy targetRange`
So I understand how to maybe copy on an active sheet but I'm unsure on how to copy across multiple sheets that may not be active.

Comment: You say you know how to use `ActiveSheet` but not how to reference other sheets yet your example contains multiple references to sheets (that do not have to be active). `Sheets(1)` and `newSheet` are used to specify ranges on specific sheets while `ActiveSheet` is not used at all..?

Comment: I was more looking at if it was possible to copy without the need for a specific reference, the titles of the sheets change so the `newSheet` name becomes incorrect. I was hoping to copy onto 3 or 4 sheets at a time, with varying names, that are already present on the workbook.

Answer (score 1):

You code use something like this

```
Sub Main
  Dim cellsToCopy As Range
  Dim shtNames as Variant, shtName As Variant

  Set cellsToCopy = Worksheets("CoverSheet").Range("D5, D11, I3, I12") '<--| change both "CoverSheet" name and its cells address list to fit your needs

  shtNames = Array("firstSheet", "secondSheet", "thirdSheet") '<--| change sheets names to paste cellsToCopy values into

  For Each shtName in shtNames
     Worksheets(shtName).Range(cellsToCopy.Address).Value = cellsToCopy.Value
  Next shtName

End Sub
```